# Angular 6 doesn't show errors properly (it shows just ERROR Error: "[object Object]" )

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm now learning Angular 6 and I'm playing around to see if I'm able to solve some errors if I'm encounter them. So I've commented some code like so

```
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
     // this.subscription = this.productService.getAll()
    //      .subscribe(products => this.filteredProducts = this.products = products);
```

and now I'm getting the following error

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"
>   resolvePromisehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3136:31resolvePromisehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3093:17scheduleResolveOrRejecthttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3195:17invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:17onInvokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/vendor.js:34857:24invokeTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:17runTaskhttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:28drainMicroTaskQueuehttp://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2917:25invokeTaskhttp://localhost:42007

So, as you can see, there's nothing related to the file where I have the error. Nothing like

```
Error: subscription is NULL! (see file bar.ts, line 123)
```

Can I do something to make Angular tell me what's wrong (i.e. show me the stack trace)?

Comment: Please post your textual error as text.

Comment: In an edit of your question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Mozilla bug. In Chrome it works as expected!